# Session not getting retrieved in Facebook C# SDK example

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am a newbie at ASP.net programming. This is in reference to the Facebook C# SDK, I have managed to set up all the steps required for authentication on this SDK. However, I keep getting a null from the following code:

(reference: http://csharpsdk.org/docs/web/getting-started#5)

```
var accessToken = Session["AccessToken"].ToString(); //This line returns null and crashes
var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
dynamic result = client.Get("me", new { fields = "name,id" });
string name = result.name;
string id = result.id;
```

Just like in the example, I had set up a generic handler to set up the session variable to be stored in the HttpContext.Session object.

I even tried to modify the offending line to directly access the HttpContext and retrieve the access token:

```
var accessToken = HttpContext.Current.Session["AccessToken"].ToString();
```

but this yielded the same result.

Have I missed out something in the webconfig or is there some other way I can store the access token when shifting from the handler to the log in page?

Comment: Have you set the `AccessToken` value in the Session before you're trying to get it out of there?

Comment: Yes I set it in the FacebookLogin Generic handler just like in the example at http://csharpsdk.org/docs/web/getting-started#5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is returning null then I would assume that the Session value is not being set - have you debugged to make sure the code which sets the session is being hit?

Looking at the linked article - it uses a HttpHandler to do this bit but does not mention anything about registering it in the Web.Config - have you done this? If not see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy.aspx

Comment: Thanks! I will try this out and let you know if it works. I publish the website I am trying it out in Azure. Is there a way to set a trace or a log so that I can see whether the information is being stored in the handler?

Comment: It would be easier to debug locally but you can add the trace attribute to your page which will give you a trace of session vars etc see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94c55d08.aspx

Comment: I'm trying to make it work but it is giving me errors. Is there an alternative to using a handler to get and store the access token?

Comment: What errors are you getting? maybe update your question with the errors so other people might be able to help

Comment: So I finally got it working! I added the following information to web.config: 
    <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="Session" />
      <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>
    </modules>
    <system.webServer>

and

<system.web>
<sessionState mode="InProc"></sessionState>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
and it worked! So I didn't have to dapple with HttpHandlers for IIS but thanks for the help Kevin! Really appreciate it because it helped me find the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure in your Facebook developer settings that you do not have query string selected for your app as auth token paramenter!!!

This is the default mode and this wont work unless you do the following:

http://developer.facebook.com

Open your app page.

Then go Settings --> Auth Dialog --> Auth Token Parameter and select URI Fragment.

100% sure this is your problem.  It's not included in any literature I found, and it's a damn shame.